# fetch_assoc() not returning data

Tags: php

$session is accepting values like 2015-16, 2016-17, 2017-18 followed by an SQL query to fetch the data from MySQL. In the last statement, json object returning $option only for 2015-16 and 2016-17. For 2017-18, it is returning null.

```
include "../session-check.php";
include "../../connection/index.php";
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

//fetching data
$session = $_POST['cmbImageSession'];
$q = "SELECT id, event_name FROM gallery WHERE session='$session' ORDER BY event_name";
$r = $conn->query($q);
$option = "<option value='0'>-- Select Event --</option>";
if($r->num_rows){
    while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
        $eid = $row['id'];
        $event_name = $row['event_name'];
        $option .= "<option value='$eid'>$event_name</option>";
    }
}
$conn->close();
echo json_encode(array("response"=>"1","option"=>$option));
```

Comment: Try printing the raw query, before executing it, then run it on SQL or PHPMyAdmin or whatever software you are using. To check whether the query is good! Then we'll go forward.

Comment: if 2 of 3 values return a result, then it is safe to assume the issue is with the 3rd value and not the code.

Comment: what is the `event_name` value for the row with "2017-18" . Im wondering if it has special characters thats breaking your HTML. What id you `var_dump($row)` on every iteration before turning it into JSON. What you get?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @the.salman.a . I have checked it thoroughly on phpMyAdmin. The query is working fine. Even **$r->num_rows** is returning correct number of rows for 2017-18 and therefore there is not any issue with value.

Comment: Everything looks okay. Just debug a little on every step from execution of query to the last step, you'll figure it out. It's not any big issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone for their prompt response. As suggested by `@the.salman.a`, I cant say it a bug but I have a alphanumeric data that was creating a problem in call from ajax. I corrected it to alphabetic and now it is working fine.